# see only functions in pycharm structure tool

Tags: pycharm

I am trying to see all the functions that I have in a python script, there is the structure tool but it also show other variables, it there a way to see only the functions in the structure tool.

Thanks,
Oren.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to disable **Show Fields** and **Show Inherited** in Structure tool window.

Follows picture to more details.

[image]

In this way, you can limit what you see in structure file.

Look at [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/viewing-structure-of-a-source-file.html#showAllMembers)